# Android service connection policy

Tags: android, service, android-activity

What is the best practice - let each Activity maintain its own connection to Service, or create a static class that holds a single Service connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assume those are your only two options. Of those two, the former is the only one that is possible, using your literal terms.

Personally, I recommend you consider the command pattern wherever possible -- use `startService()` to send a command (in the form of an `Intent`) to the service, which does the work and calls `stopSelf()` when appropriate. This works well with an `IntentService`, as the `IntentService` will process the command on a background thread and automatically calls `stopSelf()` when there is no more work to be done.

Comment: My service is required to run all the time in background, and app is connecting to it on user's demand. So I use ServiceConnection, specifying service interface using AIDL.

Comment: @Punkoff: "My service is required to run all the time in background" -- users can terminate your service whenever they want, and Android will terminate the service whenever it wants. Unless this is a VOIP client or something similar, it is likely that your service can and should be rewritten to not "run all the time in the background".

Comment: @CommonsWare, well, not exactly **all** the time. It's a media player, and it continues to run as long as media plays. I use ServiceConnection to maintain control session and callbacks. The problem is that I have >10 activities and each needs to access the service. So I'm afraid that making new connection for each activity can lead to a slowdown.

Comment: @Punkoff: OK. Your service should be just playing back music. Pretty much every media player I have used on Android (which is several) would only need to talk to the service from one activity, or maybe two. If you are concerned about potential overhead from binding to your service from 10+ activities, perhaps you might consider why you think that you need to bind to the service from 10+ activities. For example, if you are binding just to be notified of when the service switches songs, have your service send a broadcast `Intent`, and have interested activities register receivers for it.

Comment: At least, each activity needs to read current song title on Activity startup (as they have 'now playing' indicator). Even if I use service command interface (`startService`), I suppose it will still initiate a new service connection - right? So maybe it's a good idea to maintain a shared connection (attached to application's `Context`) for these small tasks?

Comment: @Punkoff: There is no "connection" for the command pattern, only for the binding pattern. For read-only-and-on-demand information like current song, I'd just have the service stick the information in a static data member. Yes, it's ugly. However, binding to services can be very annoying, particularly when it comes to configuration changes (e.g., screen rotations). Hence, I'd trade off a small amount of ugly (some static String data member with a song title) for a large amount of nasty (properly handling bindings in 10+ activities).